# Bind a function in service to $scope (Error: Cannot set property 'onChange' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to bind a function declared in the service to a controller. I am basically trying to bind the onChange function in service to onChange function in the controller $scope. 
I am getting this error:

> angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot set property 'onChange' of undefined

Here is my service

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $rootScope) {
this.selected = {
        item: '' 
}
this.getData = function(key){
    return $http.get('/myapp/stocklist/AMZN');
}
this.gs = [];
var sr = [];
this.siri=[];
var vm=this;

this.cleanData = function(response){
    for( var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++ ) {
        vm.gs.push(response.data[i].name);
        sr.push(response.data[i].high);
    }                       
    vm.siri.push(sr);
}
this.onChange = function(key){
    vm.getData(key).then(function(response){
        vm.cleanData(response);
        console.log(vm.siri);
    });
}
});
```

And controller:

```
app.controller('select', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService) {
$scope.selected = myService.selected;   
$http.get('/myapp/stocknames').
$scope.onChange = myService.onChange(); // why is this giving error? how do I do it?
success(function(data) {
    $scope.names=data;
    console.log($scope.names);          
});
}]);
```

Can you please help

Comment: the controller code does not look valid.  Is that `success` in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a correction to Ahmed's answer. You need to refer the service method as a reference and not the result of executing it. So the code above needs to be updated as:

```
app.controller('select', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService) {
   $scope.selected = myService.selected;   
   $scope.onChange = myService.onChange;
   $http.get('/myapp/stocknames').
     success(function(data) {
       $scope.names=data;
       console.log($scope.names);          
     });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just put the `$scope.onChange = myService.onChange();` in the wrong place, try:

```
app.controller('select', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope,$http, myService) {
$scope.selected = myService.selected;   
$scope.onChange = myService.onChange();
$http.get('/myapp/stocknames').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.names=data;
    console.log($scope.names);          
});
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

After Ahmed answer,
If you want to bind to the function and not to the result of the function,
you have to set to function and not to his result.
In your case:

```
$scope.onChange = myService.onChange;
```

and not:

```
$scope.onChange = myService.onChange();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the error

$http.get('/myapp/stocknames')`.`
$scope.onChange = myService.onChange();

There is a dot `.` after the

```
$http.get('/myapp/stocknames')
```

replace that with semicolon because javascript understand that in this way

> $http.get('/myapp/stocknames').$scope.onChange = myService.onChange();

Thanks